# Table Join in Rails Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a film model

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :film_genres
  has_many :genres, through: :film_genres 
end
```

a genre model

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :film_genres
  has_many :films, through: :film_genres
end
```

and then I have my filmGenre model

```
class FilmGenre < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :film
  belongs_to :genre
end
```

Im try to get a list of films in the controller under a particular Genre, but cant seem to get a join to work.

```
  def show
    @films = ## need a join / select here to fetch all films with Genre.id of 4
  end
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `includes` to join the genres table and then you can reference it in the `where` conditions:

```
@films = Film.includes(:genres).where(genres: {id: 4})
```

Alternatively, it might be easier to get all the films for genre 4 by starting with the `Genre` model:

```
@films = Genre.find(4).films
```

Comment: Thanks. Both worked, went with the second option as it reads nicer.